# What do you call the hair that falls on your forehead?

Tags: word-request

For example, when you have a bowl cut, you have hair that hides your forehead. What do you call the hair that falls on your forehead?

Comment: Fringe, or forelock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called "bangs".

According to [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bangs#bangs_3):

> **bangs** (*plural noun*) short hair that hangs over your forehead. The British word is a *fringe*.